# Django Fernet Fields : InvalidToken at / No exception message supplied

Tags: python, django

I am running a website using Django . The error i am getting is below:

Internal Server Error: /

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "C:\Users\Android V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 104, in _verify_signature
        h.verify(data[-32:])
      File "C:\Users\Android V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 66, in verify
        ctx.verify(signature)
      File "C:\Users\Android V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py", line
    74, in verify
        raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
    cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.
      File "C:\Users\Android V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 106, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
    cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

When i login to the ip: 127.0.0.1:8000, i am getting like this :`InvalidToken at /
No exception message supplied

What am i missing?`

views.py:

```
def index(request,pk=None):
# rpk=request.user.pk
if request.user.is_anonymous:
    news_portal=NewsPort.objects.all()
    news_little=NewsPort.objects.all()[1:5]
    news_first=NewsPort.objects.all()[1:5]
    return render(request,'accounts/index.html',{'pk': request.user.pk,'news_portal':news_portal,'slug':'',
                                                 'news_little':news_little, 'news_first':news_first, })
else:
    profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    news_portal=NewsPort.objects.all()
    news_little=NewsPort.objects.all()[1:5]
    news_first=NewsPort.objects.all()[0]
    return render(request,'accounts/index.html',{'profile':profile,'pk': profile.pk, 'news_first':news_first,
                                                 'news_portal': news_portal,'news_little': news_little,})
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback and the related code to your question.

Comment: I have edited. Please check.

Comment: please provide your code as currently all we know is that your code trying to decrypt something and it can't decrypt it

Comment: I have given my code . The index page is not able to decrypt.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the code that want to decrypt it would be helpful. But at the moment in [document](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) it has provided a short description :
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken – If the token is in any way invalid, this exception is raised. A token may be invalid for a number of reasons: it is older than the ttl, it is malformed, or it does not have a valid signature.

Comment: I have given my code . The index page is not able to decrypt.